# What is the difference between "select" vs "depends" in the Linux kernel Kconfig?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, configuration

What are the differences in dependencies between `select` and `depends on` in the kernels Kconfig files?

```
config FB_CIRRUS
tristate "Cirrus Logic support"
depends on FB && (ZORRO || PCI)
select FB_CFB_FILLRECT
select FB_CFB_COPYAREA
select FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT
---help---
This enables support for Cirrus Logic GD542x/543x based boards on
Amiga: SD64, Piccolo, Picasso II/II+, Picasso IV, or EGS Spectrum.
```

In the example above, how is `FB_CIRRUS` diffrently related to `FB && (ZORRO || PCI)` than it is to `FB_CFB_FILLRECT`, `FB_CFB_COPYAREA` and `FB_CFB_IMAGEBLIT`?

**Update**

I've noticed that `depend on` doesn't really do much in terms of compilation order.

For example. A successful build of AppB depends on a statically linked LibB to be built first. Setting `depends on LibB` in Kconfig for AppB will not force the LibB to be built first. Setting `select LibB` will.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`depends on A` indicates the symbol(s) `A` must already be positively selected (`=y`) in order for this option to be configured.  For example, `depends on FB && (ZORRO || PCI)` means `FB` must have been selected, and (&&) either `ZORRO` or (||) `PCI`. For things like `make menuconfig`, this determines whether or not an option will be presented.

`select` positively sets a symbol.  For example, `select FB_CFB_FILLRECT` will mean `FB_CFB_FILLRECT=y`.  This fulfills a potential dependency of some other config option(s).  Note that the kernel docs discourage the use of this for "visible" symbols (which can be selected/deselected by the user) or for symbols that themselves have dependencies, since those *will not* be checked.

Reference: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig-language.txt

Comment: and there is now `imply A` which makes variable A=y but you can also set A=n or A=m. https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-kbuild/patch/1476920573-14384-2-git-send-email-nicolas.pitre@linaro.org/

Answer (score 4):

`depends` means that the option only shows up in the menu if its prerequisites (the boolean construct behind it) are met.

`select` means that, when the user selects this option, the option given as argument to `select` will be auto-selected.

Answer (score 2):

I like to think about is as:

- `select` is a "subset" of `depends`, for when there is only one possible dependency for a feature.

  Since there is only one possible dependency, `select` just selects that option automatically, and saves you the work of explicitly picking the dependency manually first.

  This automation is what you gain from the subset restriction of having only one possible dependency.
- `depends` is more general, and works on cases where a feature depends on an interface that has multiple implementations.

  For example, on 4.15, there are 2 BPF implementations: Classic and Extended.

  Therefore, the `BPF_JIT` feature depends on at least one of the implementations being enabled:

  ```
  config BPF_JIT
      depends on HAVE_CBPF_JIT || HAVE_EBPF_JIT
  ```

  Since there are two possible implementations for `BFP_JIT`, Kconfig could not sensibly select the right one automatically.

  Sometimes I wish I could say: "if none of the dependencies is met, select this one by default" though, that would allow to further automate stuff.

There are also "something hides another option on menuconfig" effects, but these are just fluff :-)